# Another CURL to C# conversion attempt

Tags: c#, curl, httpclient, restful-authentication

Here is my CURL example, provided by the API author:

```
$data = array("username" => "XX", "password" => "XX");
$data_string = json_encode($data);
$ch = curl_init('https://<url excluded>');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data_string);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 2);
//Attached the path to .CRT file
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CAINFO, getcwd() ."/AddTrustExternalCARoot.crt");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type: application/json', 'Content-Length: '
. strlen($data_string))
);
$result = curl_exec($ch);
echo $result;
```

The method should return an alphanumeric API key for use in subsequent API calls.  All of my attempts using WebClient and HttpRequest have returned either 400 or 403 errors.

Any help I can get figuring out the correct C# library and syntax would be great.

Comment: Take a look at http://restsharp.org, it provides everything you need

Answer (score 0):

using RestSharp and clarifying the communication requirements with the API provider allowed me to get this working.  Thanks for the suggestion.